# Get default stop word list in elastic search

Tags: search, elasticsearch, documentation

I am trying to find out what the predefined stop word list for elastic search are, but i have found no documented read API for this.

So, i want to find the word lists for [this predefined variables](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-stop-tokenfilter.html) (`_arabic_, _armenian_, _basque_, _brazilian_, _bulgarian_, _catalan_, _czech_, _danish_, _dutch_, _english_, _finnish_, _french_, _galician_, _german_, _greek_, _hindi_, _hungarian_, _indonesian_, _irish_, _italian_, _latvian_, _norwegian_, _persian_, _portuguese_, _romanian_, _russian_, _sorani_, _spanish_, _swedish_, _thai_, _turkish_`)

I found the [english stop word list](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/stopwords.html) in the documentation, but I want to check if it is the one my server really uses and also check the stop word lists for other languages.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The stop words used by the English Analyzer are the same as the ones defined in the [Standard Analyzer](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/53981795fd73e85aae1892c3c72344af7c57083a/lucene/core/src/java/org/apache/lucene/analysis/standard/StandardAnalyzer.java#L44-L50), namely the ones you found in the documentation.

The stop word files for all other languages can be found in the Lucene repository in the [`analysis/common/src/resources/org/apache/lucene/analysis`](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/tree/master/lucene/analysis/common/src/resources/org/apache/lucene/analysis) folder.

Comment: Thanks! A note: I looked over the files in the folder, more popular languages (e.g english, german) seem to be located in the 'snowball' directory instead of own language folders.

Comment: @PaulWeber I don't think this answer is correct because the English list in the Lucene repository is not the same as the list in the ElasticSearch docs: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/stopwords.html

Comment: @Emilio the page you link to is pretty old, the stop words list has probably evolved a little bit.

Comment: That link isn't working for me, but I think the repository has just moved; https://github.com/apache/lucene/tree/main/lucene/analysis/common/src/resources/org/apache/lucene/analysis seems to be the equivalent link now.